# Adding a 0s to a number, dependent on how long the original string is in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers which varying in length (some of the numbers are 9 characters, while others are 7). I need them to all be 9 characters so I want to add 0s in front of the numbers. For example, if I have the number 0294843 which is 7 characters long, I want to add 2 zeros in the front, so 000284843. Since every number has different lengths (some are 9, 8, 7, 6, etc.) I'd like to find a function that will automatically add zeros dependent on the length. So far I have this:

```
=IF(LEN(D5)<9, D5, ...)
```

Where the ... is what I'm not sure what to put in. Thanks!

Comment: `=RIGHT("000000000" & D5, 9)`

Comment: As @Rotem pointed out, no need for formulas! Just select your column and add a Custom Formatting as nine zeros: 000000000

Comment: @Mariam I guess it matters whether he wants "soft" display zeroes or "hard" data zeroes. In the former, if you did ="<" & A1 & ">" where A1 is 256, it would come out as <256> as opposed to <000000256> for the latter which is probably what most people would want. In any case, he has lots of alternatives, one should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`=TEXT(A1,"000000000")`
Where A1 is the cell to pad and the number of 0s is the length you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use formulas for formatting.
Simply use a custom format. From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/81518):

> When you want to display leading zeros for a fixed-length number,
>   create a custom format with the same number of zeros (0) as digits
>   that you want to display. For example, if you want to display a
>   fixed-length number with five digits, create a custom number format
>   with five zeros.

In your case the custom format would be `000000000`